# I am building a path planning and obstacle avoidance bot using ros, lidar, etc . Can someone please provide a python program to implement?

Tags: ros, gmapping, raspberry-pi, path-planning, obstacle-avoidance

I am building a robot to perform path planning using djikstra algorithm and obstacle avoidance using gaussian potential field. The robot uses raspberry Pi 4 with ubuntu 20.04 os containing gazebo, ros noetic and rviz. It has 4 motors, 2 l298n motor drivers and tf luna lidar. I need a code containing path planning using djikstra Algorithm, obstacle avoidance, perception mapping, motor control and getting values from lidar preferably in python. As I am new to this, can someone please help me? I was trying to search for code and found these:

1.Djikstra+motor control:

```
    from gpiozero import Motor
import time

# Define motor pins and create motor objects
flmotor = Motor(forward=16, backward=17)
frmotor = Motor(forward=18, backward=13)
blmotor = Motor(forward=9, backward=11)
brmotor = Motor(forward=10, backward=12)

# Define a function to perform Dijkstra's algorithm for path planning
def dijkstra(graph, start):
    distances = {node: float('inf') for node in graph}
    distances[start] = 0
    visited = set()
    queue = [start]

    while queue:
        current = min(queue, key=lambda node: distances[node])
        queue.remove(current)

        for neighbor, weight in graph[current].items():
            distance = distances[current] + weight
            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                queue.append(neighbor)

    return distances

# Example path planning function
def plan_path():
    # Example graph representing the map
    graph = {
        'A': {'B': 5, 'C': 3},
        'B': {'A': 5, 'C': 2, 'D': 1},
        'C': {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'D': 4, 'E': 6},
        'D': {'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'E': 7},
        'E': {'C': 6, 'D': 7}
    }
    
    start_node = 'A'
    distances = dijkstra(graph, start_node)

    # Sort the distances dictionary by values
    sorted_distances = sorted(distances.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

    # Extract the waypoints from the sorted distances
    waypoints = [node for node, _ in sorted_distances]

    return waypoints

# Movement functions
def move_forward():
    flmotor.forward()
    frmotor.forward()
    blmotor.forward()
    brmotor.forward()

def stop_motors():
    flmotor.stop()
    frmotor.stop()
    blmotor.stop()
    brmotor.stop()

# Main function for autonomous control
def main():
    waypoints = plan_path()
    for waypoint in waypoints:
        # Move the robot towards the waypoint (not implemented in this example)
        move_forward()
        time.sleep(1)  # Simulated movement time
        print(f"Reached waypoint: {waypoint}")

    # Reached last waypoint, stop the motors
    stop_motors()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

2. Obstacle avoidance:

   ```
    import rospy
    from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
    from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
    from gpiozero import Motor
    import time

    # ... (Dijkstra's algorithm and path planning functions remain the same)

    class ObstacleAvoidanceRobot:
        def __init__(self):
            # ... (motor setup and ROS node initialization remain the same)

        def run(self):
            while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                try:
                    # Plan a path to the goal
                    waypoints = self.plan_path(self.graph, 'A', 'E')  # Adjust start and end nodes as needed

                    # Navigate towards waypoints with obstacle avoidance
                    for waypoint in waypoints:
                        self.navigate_to_waypoint(waypoint)

                    self.stop_motors()  # Reached destination
                except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
                    pass

        def navigate_to_waypoint(self, waypoint):
            target_x, target_y = waypoint
            curr_x, curr_y = 0, 0  # Initialize current position (adjust as needed)

            while (curr_x, curr_y) != (target_x, target_y):
                laser_data = rospy.wait_for_message('/scan', LaserScan)  # Wait for LiDAR data
                self.update_position(laser_data)  # Implement this function for positioning

                if self.obstacle_detected(laser_data):
                    self.avoid_obstacle()
                else:
                    self.move_toward_waypoint(waypoint)

        def move_toward_waypoint(self, waypoint):
            # Calculate direction and move forward (implement this logic)
            pass

        # ... (obstacle avoidance functions remain the same)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        robot = ObstacleAvoidanceRobot()
        robot.run()
   ```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 2):

Use navigation stack of ROS. You will probably need to learn more stuff, but otherwise you would reimplement massive amount of parts, which is imo loss of time.

Doing this from ground up in python is maybe good for learning, but then you should study algorithms, code structure, not asking: "Please help me get these 15 things working!"

If you go ROS way, search for: **ROS, TF, odometry, mapping, localization, navstack, global mapping, local mapping.**

I made [something similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjAa_kfo6S0) and just from *debugging/visualization* point of view, I wouldn't want to do it from ground up :)

BTW, I made [similar setup](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/c6rpKZGmOfw) to what you are describing 5 years ago. Nowadays I would try to **ROSsify** it somehow. There are videos on YouTube of people building their ROS robots so I would  start there.